# Updating component state inside array.map() causing too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ethereum, moralis

```
import useState from "react-usestateref";

const [meta, setMeta, metaRef] = useState({});
```

Inside component's JSX:

```
data.result.map((token) => {
                        const id = token.token_id;
                        const params = { uri: token.token_uri };

                        if (token.metadata) {
                            setMeta(JSON.parse(token.metadata));
                        } else {
                            Moralis.Cloud.run("get_token_uri", params).then(
                                (response) => setMeta(response)
                            );
                        }
                        const { name, description, imageUrl } = metaRef.current;
                        return (
                            <Card
                                key={id}
                                tokenId={id}
                                name={name}
                                description={description}
                                user_address={user_address}
                                imageUrl={fixURL(imageUrl)}
                                calledFrom={calledFrom}
                            />
                        );
                    })
```

I want to update the meta state variable from inside data.result.map and use the updated meta object to return a Card component. I'm using react-usestateref to get the current value of the meta state variable. Otherwise, meta still remains {} when de-structuring, even after being updated. If token.metadata is not null I want to set the meta state var to token.metadata obj and if it is null, I want to make an asynchronous request to get back the object from Moralis and then set it to the meta state var. This code is producing the following error: Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

How can I make this code work as intended?

Comment: Don't update state in the render. Instead use a useEffect, or some callback function which runs on an event trigger

Comment: You shouldn't set state in the `JSX` o r in `render`. If you are doing it then It will create infinite loop and causes rerender., which as a developer you should avoid it